# Obtener valor de un div

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenas tengo un AJAX donde consulto en una base de datos la selección que hago en un select, y según resultado lo imprimo en un div, que se llama `valorPrecio`.

**Mi AJAX**

```
      $.ajax({                        
           type: "GET",                 
           url : "{{URL::to('medidas')}}",                    
           data:{'idproducto':$value,
                'medida':$medida},
           beforeSend: function() {
               $('#valorPrecio').html('<img src="{{ asset('images/loading.gif')}}" class="loading">');
           },
           success: function(data)            
           {   

            document.getElementById("medida").value = (data.listado);
            var a = $("#valorPrecio").html(); 
            console.log(a);
            if (data.pvpOferta === null){
                $('#valorPrecio').html(data.precio);
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","none");
                $('#simboloEuro').css("display","none");
            }else{
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').html(data.precio);
                $('#valorPrecio').html(data.pvpOferta);
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","inline-block");
                $('#simboloEuro').css("display","inline-block");
            }
              
          }
        });
```

Estoy intentando así: `var a = $("#valorPrecio").html();` pero solo extraigo lo que viene en el `beforeSend`. Como puedo sacar el valor??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta obtener el valor después del if y el else, ya que cuando asignas el valor a la variable a, aún no has modificado el valor del div. así:

```
            if (data.pvpOferta === null){
                $('#valorPrecio').html(data.precio);
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","none");
                $('#simboloEuro').css("display","none");
            }else{
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').html(data.precio);
                $('#valorPrecio').html(data.pvpOferta);
                $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","inline-block");
                $('#simboloEuro').css("display","inline-block");
            }

            var a = $("#valorPrecio").html(); 
            console.log(a);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, mira que lo intente pero no me lleve el `console.log` abajo tambien. Muchas gracias funciono y bienvenido!

Comment: me alegro, a todos nos ha pasado algo parecido con detalles. Muchas gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Según te entiendo, estás tratando de mostrar antes de mandar la request un icono de "Loading..." al usuario.  Esto no lo deberías de hacer en el beforeSend del AJAX, porque el beforeSend se usa mas que nada para agregar parametros al header de la request que vas a hacer al backend, según la documentación:

**beforeSend**

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings ) A pre-request
> callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery
> 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as
> arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend
> function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend
> option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Puedes intentar antes del llamado ajax te agregar esa imagen y luego en el success callback puedes ocultarla/borrarla dado que la respuesta ya la recibiste.

Adicional, si tu elemento ID valorPrecio es un DIV entonces debes de usar el **$("#valorPrecio").text(data.precio)** de JQuery para mostrar el resultado.

Espero te sirva,

Saludos